# How to drag components across panels in java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Is it possible to drag a JLabel from one panel to another?
I can only drag the label within one panel. When the label moves out of the burden, it just disappear. I don't know what to do.

Comment: Which `GUI editor` are you using?

Comment: @PM77-1: what does the editor have to do with this? He's using the Swing library and that's all that matters.

Comment: I somehow thought that the question was about the `design process` and not about `run-time`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to remove the label from its current container when you start dragging it. Normally we add it to the glass pane to allow for the illusion of been dragged across multiple components.

Take a look at [My drag is better then yours](http://rabbit-hole.blogspot.com.au/2006/05/my-drag-image-is-better-than-yours.html) for an example. I'd also recommend that you have a dig around his site, he does some nice work with drag and drop

Answer (score 5):

You can easily do this in several ways. One way is to

- bump the label to the glass pane on `mousePressed(...)`
- drag it in the glass pane on `mouseDragged(...)`,
- then drop it down to whatever container the mouse is currently over on `mouseReleased(...)`.